# Error in installing R package headers/libs are not available

Tags: compiling, r

I am installing the R package (`R-3.0.1`) in Red Hat Linux 6.0.

Initially when I tried to install it gave the error “F77 compiler not found”. I installed the compiler and tried it again, now the error I am getting is

```
configure: error: --with-readline=yes (default) and headers/libs are not available
```

I tried `./configure --with-x=no` but it doesn't work, again I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with all this trouble. Just `yum install R`; it's in the [EPEL repository](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL), which [you should already be using](https://serverfault.com/a/480995/126632).

Comment: Hi Micheal, thanks for the reply.. i am getting error in installing R Could you please tell how to get EPEL for Redhat 6.0 ?? i mentioned the error i am getting .. yum install R
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit
Setting up Install Process
No package R available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: Don't use Red Hat unless you've actually paid for it and registered the machine. If you aren't willing or able to pay for it, use CentOS instead.

Comment: I think my Redhat is registered..

Comment: Hi,i couldnt rectify the problem.. i gave yum install R but it shows there is no package R..

Comment: Did you add the epel repository as Michael H wrote in his answer?

Comment: HI, i gave yum install R but it shows error as mentioned below Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit
Setting up Install Process
No package R available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: could anybody suggest on the same. during installation (./configure make) it gives error as Invalid declaration of or reference to symbol `tiny' at (^) [initially seen at (^)]

Comment: Hello Jenny, in the EPEl it is mentioned it should be present in the linux system by default (http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) Could you please tell me how to add it?? Thanks

Comment: Hello Sridhar, the link you are posting is to Fedora. Earlier you said you are running Redhat. If you are indeed running Redhat, what you need to do is follow the link to EPEL repository that Michael posted. On that page it says "How do I use the extra packages". Follow the instructions there for your operating instruction.

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestions jenny..I installed epel package and tried it(yum install R). again it shows error as

Error: Package: R-core-3.0.1-2.el6.x86_64 (epel) Requires: libjpeg.so.62(LIBJPEG_6.2)(64bit) Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.0.1-2.el6.x86_64 (epel) Requires: texinfo-tex You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

I download the library package and install it "rpm -Uvh libjpeg-turbo-1.2.90-2.fc20.i686.rpm" but again it gives the same Error during executing "yum install R"

Please suggest on the same
Thanks
Sridhar